# bin/rake db:create error on MacOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently working on installing the sugar forum in ruby on rails, and running it on localhost:3000. I'm having trouble on running the db:create command without getting errors ran the following command:

```
bin/rake db:create
```

I provided my password and got this error:

```
Access denied for user 'rails'@'localhost' (using password: YES)Please provide the root password for your MySQL installation
```

I provided the password that I have in my database.yml file under the 'mysql' section. My file looks like this:

```
mysql: &mysql
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  username: <%= ENV['SUGAR_DB_USERNAME'] || "rails" %>
  password: <%= ENV['SUGAR_DB_PASSWORD'] || "rails" %>
  database: <%= ENV['SUGAR_DB_DATABASE'] || "sugar_#{Rails.env}" %>
```

All I did was just follow the installation guide in the git repo of 'sugar'.

Repo URL:

- https://github.com/elektronaut/sugar

I hope somebody can help me with this since it's so frustrating and wasting my time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the root password for your MySQL installation, not the password for the database you're creating.

When you installed MySQL on your local machine, you created a password for the root user for the entire install. This is the password it's asking for as Rails is trying to create the new database for you.

The credentials you provide in the database.yml are for the new database you're creating for the sugar install only.

Comment: I have one morer problem now. I don't remember my password. I don't even remember setting one. Can you help me out?

Comment: You'll need to reset the root password on MySQL: https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords